# How to invoke rails migration generator programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Simply Running `rails g` from command line suffers from long time of pre-loading. I want to fast generate multiple migrations from a running `rails c`, so I tried:

```
require 'rails/generators'
Rails::Generators.invoke('migration',['user_book_list_followings'],{:behavior=>:invoke, :destination_root=>Rails.root})
```

You ask where did I get that :behavior and :destination_root arguments? Well, I pried at the Rails::Generators#invoke execution point when I run the generator from the command and recorded the exact arguments.

However, the funny thing was, I was presented with a error saying:

> No value provided for required options '--orm'

Did I miss anything? (I was on Rails 3.2.3)

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'rails/generators'
Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:migration", ["create_something", "list_order:string", "name:string"], {migration: true, timestamps: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to speed up callings rails g, is using [spring.](https://github.com/rails/spring)

> Spring is a Rails application preloader. It speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background so you don't need to boot it every time you run a test, rake task or migration.